# Insufficient Data getting Parsed in the Facebook Graph API

Tags: java, android, json, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get facebook feeds of a page. When I open this link in browser, the full json appears with no problem but when I parse it using following code only the first two posts get displayed in app.

```
    url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/awaaziitkgp/feed?access_token="
            + static_token;
```

for parsing, i am doing this

```
ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
    String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                        // Getting JSON Array node
                        contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_DATA);
                        String x = null;
                        Log.d("contact.length", x.valueOf(contacts.length()));
                        // looping through All Contacts
                        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                            String message = c.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);// feed
                            String createtime = c.getString(TAG_CREATETIME);// date,
                                                                            // time
                            Log.d("POSTS", message); // created
```

The first two json objects are getting parsed correctly, but the rest are not visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two of your JSONObjects are getting parsed without any problem. I think the field "message" that you are searching is not available in your third object.

Check you JSON properly. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. The problem was is JSON file. Some of the posts didn't contain message field, that's why on third post due to no "message" field, JSONObject returned empty and terminated the loop.
I'd added `if (c.has("message") == true)`before getting data from message field to avoid null JSONObject.